# Compute an indefinite sequence of And

Tags: sequence, boolean-computation

I would like to compute a condition of normalization over a set of vectors which has the form $$ (x_1.x_1 =1 ) \land ...\land (x_n.x_n=1) $$ Where the $x_i$ are vectors, and $n$ is a variable fixed at the beginning of the code which specifies the number of vectors.
The purpose here is to solve a set of equations over the 2-sphere i.e. to use Solve with the condition that all the variables (vectors) have unit length.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to use the And function for this scope !

Is there a way to compute such a condition for an arbitrary number of vectors ?

Edit : Sorry I did a mistake in the formula.. Now the question should be clearer

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean with `1∧...`? 1 isn't a Boolean.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but take a look at `Apply`, e.g. `And @@ {True, False, True}`.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I've updated the question - It should be clearer now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
n = 4;
```

It is generally best to avoid subscripts except in output display.

```
Format[x[k_]] := Subscript[x, k]

(expr = And @@ Table[x[i].x[i] == 1, {i, n}]) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]